# Ubuntu Live USB Misbehaving

Tags: boot, unity, usb, uefi, rufus

I am trying to make a Live USB in order to install Ubuntu on a USB drive, and I am experiencing strange behavior that prevents me from doing anything in the desktop environment once it boots.

I have tried 17.10 with Unity and 17.10 MATE on two different SanDisk Ultra Flair USB 3.0 16GB Flash Drives. I have used Rufus to create EUFI and LiLi to create legacy boot versions, and none will fully boot and work.

With LiLi non-UEFI the system booted to a blinking cursor, Ctrl-Alt-Del popped up an Ubuntu logo for a moment before rebooting.

After that I decided to stick with Rufus to use UEFI.

With Rufus, MATE boots to desktop and shows the intro window, then it detects the network. Clicking or right clicking on top menu causes all icons and menu bars to disappear, then reappear, and nothing opens. Clicking the Firefox icon gets a spinning wheel for about 10 seconds, then nothing. Moving the Welcome window causes the contents to disappear. Clicking the Install icon or the drive icon causes screen flicker then nothing. The power icon works, but basically nothing else does.

Unity behaves similarly, FF won't open, Install starts the wizard, but after the first two screens of the Install utility the system goes to the login screen (with the Live User the only option). Repeating this, occasionally there is a UI error that appears for a split second but I can't read it before the login screen appears.

Can't access Terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T) in either.

I think the MATE flicker and menu disappearance may be the same symptom as the Unity login screen, MATE auto-logs back in while Unity pops up the login screen, but something is causing the environment to restart with almost any command.

Ideas?

**Hardware:**

SanDisk Ultra Flair USB 3.0 16GB

HP z240

i7-7600

Intel HD 530 video with dual monitors at 1440P

Comment: Why try 15.04? That version of Ubuntu has reached its end of life. Please focus on currently supported versions of Ubuntu in this site.

Comment: The following link may help you select a suitable version of Ubuntu or Ubuntu community flavour, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865

Comment: Yes, we have other suggestions like posting your hardware specifications. Some high-end Nvidia graphics require a different procedure for running the live session and booting the installed system until the Nvidia drivers are installed. Other hardware may require other boot parameters. Please [edit] accordingly.

Comment: Hardware section has been called out to be more readable. It somehow ended up on one line in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the USB 3.0 ports. The log files had thousands of errors in them after boot, so they weren't much help troubleshooting.

Moving the Live USB to a non-USB 3.0 port fixed all of the problems, albeit with slower load times.

HP z240 uses intel USB 3.0 controller, C230 chipset, PNP id: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_A12F&SUBSYS_802F103C